# i can't create a new project in android studio 3.3.1

Tags: android

i can't create a new project in android studio 3.3.1.
when i try to create it shows,

[image]

but it create a folder in save location, i tried it to open but it shows another error.

[image]

and i also tried "invalidate cache and restart" method. I can open older projects that i created early, and i tried to change Sdk versions. I am using Git to add project to GitHub.

Comment: uninstall and install

Comment: no need, I found a way just reset android studio settings. delete 'AndroidStudio3.3' folder.   (C:\Users\RinceMathew\.AndroidStudio3.3).then open android studio and setup once again.